# UserRecordAccess query not returning any results

Tags: lightning, visual-flows, invocable-method

I am calling a apex method from lightning flow. Inside method, I am trying to query UserRecordAccess as below :
SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess FROM UserRecordAccess  WHERE UserId=:'005xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND RecordId=:'001xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.

Here I wan to find out if user has access to that account.

I have set the flow to run on *System Context Without Sharing - Access All Data*. Also my apex class is without sharing. Still query does not return any value. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Try to run the relevant query from developer console see if it does return result. + If it is sharing issue try writing your apex class 'without sharing'

Comment: It does return result when ran from developer console. May be because I have admin access. And when it runs from flow, probably it is running in Platform Integration User context. But I have set the flow to run on System Context Without Sharing - Access All Data. My apex class is written 'without sharing' only.